# StringUtils.isNumeric blocks JOptionPane cancel option

Tags: java, joptionpane

This is the code I'm using to process the input of an integer :

```
public static int getIntInput(String message) {
    String numberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
    while (!StringUtils.isNumeric(numberStr) || Integer.parseInt(numberStr) == 0) {
        numberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(numberStr);
}
```

It works fine, except when I want to press "cancel" or close button on the JOption window. When I do that, the JOptionPane window shows up again.

How can I correctly close a JOptionPane window when the cancel or close button is pushed?

Comment: replace `while` by `if`

Comment: @Sasha Salauyou not a very clever solution because i really want the window to show up till the user inputs a valid integer. I just want to have the option to close the window > terminate program.

Comment: so what is the problem? `showInputDialog()` returns when some input is submitted by user, then you validate it. If not valid, return something else than input value -- null or value indicating wrong input, e. g. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (!StringUtils.isNumeric(numberStr) || Integer.parseInt(numberStr) == 0) {

        if (numberStr == null) {
           return 0; 
        }
        else {
            numberStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message);
        }
}
```

This does the trick.